# Implementing Tile Controls in Silverlight

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I would like to use tile controls in silverlight 5. I searched that and I found below links.

http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TileView/FirstLook
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOxOTrZ_nPc

But they look like commercial products. I don't want to buy them.
To implement this, I want to use basic controls which `Visual Studio` provides. Then, what controls do I have to do digging first?

And are there open source controls about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: http://blacklight.codeplex.com/ for the code and http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/ for a demo. The Drag Drop Panel control looks very cool.